# How can I get gdb to stop at breakpoints when launching from within a VSCode dev container?

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

## What I'm trying to do

- Run a c++ program with gdbserver within the container, with this command

```
 bazel run -c dbg --run_under="gdbserver :12345" //home:my_program
```

- Launch gdb from VSCode dev container, and attach to the running gdbserver

## Problem I'm facing

- When I launch gdb from within the VSCode dev container, it seems to be able to attach to the gdbserver - saw the following message but the execution doesn't stop at the breakpoints.

```
Process /home/my_program created; pid = 30687
Listening on port 12345
Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1
```

- I am only able to launch gdb in VSCode from the host itself, **outside** of the dev container, and get it to attach to gdbserver **and** stop at the breakpoints.

## My setup

`launch.json` looks like

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "C++ Launch",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "/home/my_program",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
      "miDebuggerServerAddress": ":12345",
      "cwd": "/home",
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

The same config works from outside of the VSCode dev container.

## What have I tried?

1. I've tried adding the following section but that didn't help

```
      "pipeTransport": {
        "pipeCwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "pipeProgram": "docker",
        "pipeArgs": [
          "exec",
          "-i",
          "jolly_gauss",
          "sh",
          "-c"
        ],
        "debuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
      },
```

2. I've tried forwarding port 12345 in my docker container launch but that didn't help

## My question

What configs am I missing if I want to make the debugger work when launching from within the VSCode dev container?

I expect to be able to launch gdb from the dev container and connect to the gdbserver already running in the container, and stop the execution at the breakpoints.

Comment: Have you tried adding an "attach configuration" to launch.json ? With `"request": "attach"` ?

Comment: @thibaultCimic Yes I have. That didn't work for me.

Comment: And do you really need to use it via vscode ? Emacs has a pretty nice interface for gdb if you don't like the one in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason is not because of the dev container config, but that the GDB version in the dev container is too old so it cannot decode the DWARF section in my program with debugging symbols. I upgraded GDB in the dev container to V10.1 and then it worked.